# Имя переменной, в которой анонимная функция

Tags: javascript, функции, анонимная-функция

Как узнать имя объекта и его ключ, в котором находится анонимная функция из самой функции?

```js
var obj = {};
obj.f = function() {
  console.log('Пусто:', arguments.callee.name);
}
obj.f();
```

С обычной переменной так работает:

```js
var f = function() {
  console.log('Имя функции:', arguments.callee.name);
}
f();
```

Comment: можно через контекст идти по всем св-вам, пока не получим нужное:D

Comment: `Object.entries(this).filter(v => v[1] === arguments.callee)[0][0]`

Comment: но если контекст потеряется, то и ключ не найдете

Comment: @StrangerintheQ а потом автор пишет `setTimeout(obj.f)` и ( все взрывается ),  не работает(

Comment: самый безопасный способ в таких случаях не использовать анонимные функции

Comment: @ThisMan ну что ж поделать+)

Comment: у полей и свойств нет связи с их родителем, то есть по наличию функции нельзя сказать является ли она методом какого-то объекта или нет

Comment: А нет варианта попроще, типа посмотреть где лежит функция?